# Plotting the errobar in gnuplot without the use of bash or awk script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a csv data of the following format

```
1,1.234
1,1.35
1,1.194
2,1.673
2,1.674
2,1.573
```

I want to plot errorbars in gnuplot for the following data using mean and standard deviation
using only gpt script. I have plotted this using a bash script which calculates mean and standard deviation into a another temporary csv file and plotted errorbars.

**EDIT:**
**Script**
This is bash script i used

```
#! /bin/bash
iteration=1500
rerun=3
mean=0
sum=0
i=0
j=1
count=1
while read -ra f
do
  if [ $i -eq $rerun ];
  then
    i=0
    mean=$(echo "scale=5; $mean/$rerun"|bc)
    std=$(echo "scale=5; sqrt($sum/$rerun - $mean*$mean)"|bc)
    echo $j,$mean,$std >>temp.csv
    mean=0
    sum=0
    j=$(($j+1))
  fi
  f=($(echo $f | tr ',' ' '))
  mean=$( echo "scale=5; ${f[1]}+$mean" | bc)
  sum=`echo "scale=5; ${f[1]}*${f[1]}+$sum"| bc`
  i=$(($i+1))
done < input.csv
mean=$(echo "scale=5; $mean/$rerun"|bc)
std=$(echo "scale=5; sqrt($sum/$rerun - $mean*$mean)"|bc)
echo $j,$mean,$std >>temp.csv
```

**output**
This is not a actual output, but the format of this and the actual output is same

```
number,mean,std-deviation
1,1.267,0.034
2,1.567,0.012
.....
.....1500 lines
```

Comment: Post the bash script and the output you like to have.  Do you like to use `awk` or only `gnuplot` (You have added `awk` tag)

Comment: i can do it by awk. but i like to use gnuplot only

Comment: Ok, I then remove the `awk` tag.

Comment: @Jotne i added bash script and output required

Comment: For the mean value, you can use `smooth unique`, but in general you cannot compute the standard deviation of y-values with the same x-value. The `stats` command uses the whole data set. Why don't you want to use the bash script? If its only for the temporary file, consider using `plot '< bash myscript.sh' ...`

Comment: @Christoph i used bash script. But i just wanted to know if this is even possible in gnuplot